# How to prevent black and white screens while launching app in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created an IBM Worklight 6.1 application for Windows Phone 8.
I built and deployed the application to a device.

I am getting the following screens:

1. IBM Splash Screen
2. Black Screen
3. White Screen
4. Application UI

How to not-display 2 and 3?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What Worklight version do you use? what specific deveice?

Comment: @ShmulikBardosh  Worklight version: IBM Worklight 6.1 and Device: HTC 8X Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @dhineshsundar, is this only on the first launch of the application, or all application launches?

Comment: @IdanAdar Every launch of the application..

Comment: Have you tried it on an emulator? Have you walked through these Getting Started modules to ensure you aren't missing anything: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/01_07_Setting_up_your_Windows_Phone_8_development_environment.pdf  ,  http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_01_Creating_your_first_Worklight_application.pdf ,   http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_07_Previewing_your_application_on_Windows_Phone_8.pdf

Comment: @Barbara, I have tried it on emulator as well as in device but the problem is same. I have followed the procedure from Getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Some updates on the problems reported in the question:

1. "black screen after the splash image"

   This issue has been resolved. There is no local workaround available.
   An iFix can be requested for Worklight 6.1 and 6.2 by [opening a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639).
2. "white screen after black screen"

   This issue is not yet resolved, but is expected to be.
   The following temporary workaround can be applied:

   - In the generated Visual Studio project, open MainPage.xaml > MainPage.xaml.cs
   - Do the following and run in Visual Studio

   Find:

   ```
   void CordovaView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

   }
   ```

   Replace with:

   ```
   private async void CordovaView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var frame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;

       PhoneApplicationPage page = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
       WebBrowser br = (page.FindName("CordovaView") as CordovaView).Browser;
       double savedHeight = br.ActualHeight;
       br.Height = 0; // make the browser height to 0 until the html is loaded

       BitmapImage b1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("SplashScreenImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
       ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
       imgBrush.ImageSource = b1;
       frame.Background = imgBrush;
       await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); // avoid flickering
       br.Height = savedHeight;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

For dark theme- the frame background will be black; and for light theme- the frame background is white.

One possible workaround is to match the color of the Frame to the color of the first page.

To change the frame background color, you have to put the below line in the InitializePhoneApplication() of app.xaml.cs (after creation of RootFrame instance)

```
 RootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```